# Shrink down register_settings on Settings API

Tags: plugins, php, validation

Instead of having so many function calls, is there a way that I can have one function call and all the fields under one section and then just call one section on the form?

```
/**
 * Register each section
 */
function register_insta_heading()
{
    register_setting('instagram-settings','insta_heading','');
    add_settings_section('','','','insta_heading_field');
    add_settings_field('','Heading','heading_display', 'insta_heading_field','');
}

function register_insta_username()
{
    register_setting('instagram-settings','insta_username');
    add_settings_section('','','','insta_username_field');
    add_settings_field('','Username','username_display','insta_username_field','');
}

function register_insta_id()
{
    register_setting('instagram-settings','insta_id');
    add_settings_section('','','','insta_id_field');
    add_settings_field('','Instagram ID','id_display','insta_id_field','');}

function register_insta_posts()
{
    register_setting('instagram-settings','insta_posts');
    add_settings_section('','','','posts_number_field');
    add_settings_field('','# of Posts','posts_number_display','posts_number_field','');
}

function register_insta_accesstoken()
{
    register_setting('instagram-settings','insta_accesstoken');
    add_settings_section('','','','access_token_field');
    add_settings_field('','Access Token','access_token_display','access_token_field','');
}
```

The form submit:

```php
<?php
        settings_fields( 'instagram-settings' );
        do_settings_sections("insta_heading_field");
        do_settings_sections("insta_username_field");
        do_settings_sections("insta_id_field");
        do_settings_sections("posts_number_field");
        do_settings_sections("access_token_field");
        submit_button();
        ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.